# Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated

Tags: anchor, solana-program, pda, anchor-lang, program

Here is my code

```
#[program]
pub mod anchor_code {
    use super::*;

    pub fn new_wallet(ctx: Context<WalletInfo>) -> Result<()>{
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct WalletInfo<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        space = 8 + 4 + 4 + 1 + 32, seeds = [b"wallet"], bump
    )]
    pub wallet: Account<'info, Wallet>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,

}

#[account]
pub struct Wallet {
    pub owner_wal : Pubkey,
    pub owner_id : u32,
    pub points : u32,
    pub bump: u8,
}
```

Typescript client is just

```
  const wallet = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

  const tx = program.methods.newWallet().accounts({wallet:wallet.publicKey}).rpc();
```

The error logs are

```
      'Program 5zjZr7GSqcvhLVQAU4qUFfCSpio8uhPHqabP4KFumFe4 invoke [1]',
      'Program log: Instruction: NewWallet',
      'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: wallet. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.',
      'Program log: Left:',
      'Program log: 4P75awNaWZzF4ZKVtAdseVkXEAYsLYD5AhXhrzDdSPfV',
      'Program log: Right:',
      'Program log: 8UMyacKaXn4Xc1cRn2HHBiZa4qDT2ZsyswjTtF9S5vbM',
      'Program 5zjZr7GSqcvhLVQAU4qUFfCSpio8uhPHqabP4KFumFe4 consumed 8363 of 200000 compute units',
      'Program 5zjZr7GSqcvhLVQAU4qUFfCSpio8uhPHqabP4KFumFe4 failed: custom program error: 0x7d6'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The seeds constraint in your `wallet` field of the `WalletInfo` struct, mentions that the publicKey of that account should use the string "wallet" (in bytes) as seeds for deriving the address.

On the other hand, in your client, you're generating a random new keypair and passing its pubkey as the address for the wallet field.

How to solve:

```
let [walletAddr,] = await web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync([Buffer.from("wallet")], programIdOfYourProgram);

const tx = program.methods.newWallet().accounts({wallet: walletAddr}).rpc();
```

PDAs are deterministic. So in the above code, you're deriving the address of the to-be-initialized account first and then passing it as the pubkey in your account.

This should succeed because the seeds you used to generate the address on your client and the seeds that you mention as constraint, are the same.

Comment: This only works once and generates the same account every time. How can I make a new one every time? or a new one based on a certain address?

Comment: This will be unique creation per keypair account: seeds = [b"wallet", signer.key().as_ref()]. If you want multiple accounts per keypair, would need to add a counter such as: seeds = [b"wallet", signer.key().as_ref(), idx.to_be_bytes()].

Comment: yes, @mega_creamery is correct. basically when thinking of seeds for PDAs, think that if the PDA's account struct would be a SQL table, what combination of its fields would be the primary key? then use those fields as seeds and derive all the addresses you want. :)